# Anchor tag loaded through AJAX opens in new tab. How to jump in original window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Lovely People!

I have a big problem...

On my main page I'm loading content dynamically with jQuery.ajax() into a div. The content that I'm loading into the div contains anchor tags that refer to the main pages content. After loading, when I click on one of the anchor tags, it opens a new tab instead of jumping within the main page. How do I prevent this (I want to jump within the main page not open a new tab...)

The code on my main page looks something like this:

```js
     // process the form
    jQuery('#analyse').submit(function(event) {

      var formData = {
        'site': jQuery('input[name=site]').val(),
        'keywords': jQuery('input[name=keywords]').val()
      };

      // process the form
      jQuery.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/tools/onpage/analyser2.php',
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'html',
          encode: true
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          jQuery("#analyse_result").html(data);
        });
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

The content that's being loaded into the div looks something like this (simplified):

```html
<p>The title of your website is very important for SEO. Make sure your title contains your keyword. 
<a class="moreinfo" href="#atitel">More info about setting the right title here >></a>
</p>
```

... and when I click that anchor link, it opens a new tab instead of jumping within the main page.

Comment: what about setting <a href="...." target="_self">link title</a>

Comment: That really shouldn't happen, anchors with hash based hrefs don't reload the page -> **https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/u4dewqgd/**

Comment: Something else, we aren't aware of, gives you this behaviour

Comment: SORRY guys for using your time. Just found the problem. It was this in my code: jQuery('#expList a').unbind('click').click(function() {
     window.open(jQuery(this).attr('href')); return false; ... FIXED NOW!